# Flutter, GoRouter. Access to the ShellRoute Bloc from his children

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-go-router

I have this APage ShellRoute in go_router that contains 3 childrens  [BPage, CPage, DPage].

```
    TypedShellRoute<ARoute>(        
      routes: [
        TypedGoRoute<BRoute>(
          path: BRoute.path,
          name: BRoute.name,
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<CRoute>(
          path: CRoute.path,
          name: CRoute.name,
        ),
        TypedGoRoute<DRoute>(
          path: DRoute.path,
          name: DRoute.name,
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

So in the APage(ShellRoute) i have this bloc.

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   _aBloc = ABloc();
 }
 
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider.value(value: _aBloc),
        ]...
```

The problem is that I can't access ABloc from the children like this:

In the BPage

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _aBloc = context.read<ABloc>();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is because BPage is created before APage.

```
class ARoute extends ShellRouteData {
  const ARoute();

  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> $navigatorKey = _aShellNavigatorKey;

  @override
  Widget builder(context, state, navigator) { 
    return APage(      
      child: navigator, //This is created first
    );
  }
}
```

The navigator passed to the APage that contains the nested routes [BPage ,CPage, DPage] is creted first that the APage.
How i can solve this problem whit go_router and bloc?